# How to stop iFrame form from reloading on mobile?

Tags: forms, mobile, iframe

I am loading a form via an iFrame. On a desktop it works and submits correctly. However on a mobile device once the user's keyboard pops up then the iFrame refreshes, clearing the form and the keyboard disappears again. This makes it impossible to enter details into the form. Is there a way to stop WordPress from refreshing an iFrame?

https://ubleisure.co.za/
It is the first form on the main page and needs to be able to work correctly on mobile.

Comment: If this is happening it’s not WordPress that’s doing it.

Comment: This is probably JS recreating the iframe when the viewport size changes, e.g it will happen when you rotate the phone too, but it is not a WordPress issue, you need JS/frontend developer help not WordPress help. Contact the developer who built the form, or the support for the theme/plugin you used to construct it

Comment: If I put the iFrame on another site that is not WordPress I do not have this issue. I'm new to WordPress so I don't know how everything works.